# AWS Lambda / API Gateway - What is the best way to invoke a function that allows both authenticated and non authenticated requests?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

Currently I have a single method on a resource that I want both non authenticated and authenticated (using Cognito User Pools) users to access. To my understanding, API gateway only allows methods to be either authenticated or non authenticated so if I use a standard Cognito User Pool authorizer it will just deny access to all non authenticated users. My idea right now is to write a custom lambda authorizer that validates an ID token passed and forwards the claim or allows non authenticated users to pass through. Is there an easier way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Have you considered handling this from the client? The client has to forward an auth token to the API and if it doesn't exist, just route them to the "open" endpoint, targeting the same Lambda.

Comment: Yes, however I want to avoid any additional client side logic as I plan to release a public facing API to my end users in the near future. Ideally redirects are handled by the API Gateway, which it seems you provided an answer to below. Thank you

Comment: That makes sense. Give some feedback once you test it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy you could explore: Setup two endpoints: one goes through Cognito and the other allows traffic through unauthenticated but have them target the same Lambda function. Alter the API Gateway response on the authenticated endpoint to redirect on missing authentication. You'd then point the redirect to the unauthenticated endpoint.

Here's an [AWS Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-gateway-response-using-the-console.html) on setting up an API Gateway Response.